Cannot understand "Undefined Control Sequence" errors because the document seems to still compile correctly
I'm pretty new to LaTeX, and I'm having trouble with error debugging. New-command definitions are supposedly failing, but the PDF generates correctly. However, I want to fix them as future issues may arise.
Here are the error screenshoots:



And here's the code to test it:
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}

% -- MARGIN AND LAYOUT --
    \usepackage{geometry} 
    \geometry{
     includefoot,
     a4paper,
     total={170mm,257mm},
     left=27mm,
     top=40mm,
     headsep=10mm,
     right=27mm,
     bottom=27mm,
     footskip=15mm
    }
    
    % Interlineado
    \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.4} 


% -- MARGIN AND LAYOUT --

% -- COLOR SQUARE --
    \usepackage{eso-pic}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \definecolor{defaultColor}{HTML}{d9d9d9}
    \definecolor{marginColor1}{HTML}{FBE8E8}

    % Custom margin square command
    \newcommand{\marginsquare}[1]{%
        \AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
            \AtPageUpperRight{%
                \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
                    \fill[#1] ($(current page.north east)+(0,-3cm)$) rectangle ($(current page.north east)+(-1.5cm,-4.5cm)$);
                \end{tikzpicture}
            }
        }
    }

    % Apply the margin square to every page
    \newcommand{\applymarginsquare}{\AddEverypageHook{\marginsquare{marginColor1}}}


    % Initially apply the first color
    %\applymarginsquare
    
% -- COLOR SQUARE --

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lastpage} % To reference last page's number

% -- FANCY HEADER, FOOTER AND CHAPTERS --
    \usepackage{fancyhdr} % Headers and footers
    \usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}
    % Color of the chapter
    \newcommand{\colortitlechap}{\color[rgb]{0.6,0.6,0.6}} % color of the chapter title <<<
    \newcommand{\colornumberchap}{\color[rgb]{0.6,0.6,0.6}} % color of the chapter number <<<<
    \newcommand{\colorbackchap}{\colorbox{defaultColor}} % color of the background rules <<<

    \makeatletter

    \renewcommand{\DOCH}{%
    \settowidth{\py}{\CNoV\thechapter}
    \addtolength{\py}{-10pt}% 
    \fboxsep=0pt%
    \colorbackchap{\rule{0pt}{40pt}\parbox[b]{\textwidth}{\hfill}}%
    \kern-\py\raise20pt%
    \hbox{\colornumberchap\CNoV\thechapter}\\%
    }

    \renewcommand{\DOTI}[1]{%
    \nointerlineskip\raggedright%
    \fboxsep=\myhi%
    \vskip-1ex%
    \colorbackchap{\parbox[t]{\mylen}{\CTV\FmTi{\colortitlechap#1}}}\par\nobreak%
    \vskip 40\p@%
    }

    \renewcommand{\DOTIS}[1]{%
    \fboxsep=0pt%
    \colorbackchap{\rule{0pt}{40pt}\parbox[b]{\textwidth}{\hfill}}\\%
    \nointerlineskip\raggedright%
    \fboxsep=\myhi%
    \colorbackchap{\parbox[t]{\mylen}{\CTV\FmTi{\colortitlechap#1}}}\par\nobreak%
    }

    \makeatother

    % Header and footer
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \cfoot{}
    \usepackage{lastpage} % To reference last page's number
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.3mm}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0mm} % 0.3mm
    \renewcommand{\footruleskip}{0mm} % 5mm
    
    % Número de página en el pie de página
    \fancyfoot[C]{\textbf{Página \thepage \hspace{1pt} de \pageref{LastPage}}}
    
    \fancypagestyle{plain}{% % <-- this is new
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}

    % Redefine chaptermark to preserve case 
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{Capítulo \thechapter\ : #1}{}}
    \renewcommand{\chaptername}{Capítulo}

% -- FANCY HEADER, FOOTER AND CHAPTERS --


\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand*\contentsname{ÍNDICE DE CONTENIDOS}
\tableofcontents

\renewcommand{\colorbackchap}{\colorbox{marginColor1}} % color of the background rules <<<
\chapter{INTRODUCCIÓN}
% Change the margin square color for the next chapter
\renewcommand{\applymarginsquare}{\AddEverypageHook{\marginsquare{marginColor1}}}
\applymarginsquare
\section{Some dummy text}
\blindtext[10]

\end{document}


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

specific problem is the undefined control sequence. I want to solve that error when compiling. Testing the code above will show where exactly the problem is

Instead of posting screenshots of the errors it's better to copy the logfiles content and mark it as code. It will be decorated with scrollbars as needed- // Please keep in mind all here are volunterrs and making it smooth and easy helps everybody. I.e. the expereinced ones here just need a scan through your log file and don't have to compile, unless they want to try something which might become a solution: that's when your code is welcome/needed.

Welcome to TeX.SX!

thanks for the information and your help

The shown error messages are very clear: There are several undefined commands in your code. \AddEverypageHook is definitely not defined and IMHO not needed. Just use \marginsquare{…} instead. But \AtPageUpperRight is also not defined. eso-pic does define, e.g., \AtPageUpperLeft but not \AtPageUpperRight (see the package documentation for more information). But If you'd search for the command, you will find several questions/answers that show valid definitions.
I guess you want something like this:
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}

% -- MARGIN AND LAYOUT --
    \usepackage{geometry} 
    \geometry{
     includefoot,
     a4paper,
     total={170mm,257mm},
     left=27mm,
     top=40mm,
     headsep=10mm,
     right=27mm,
     bottom=27mm,
     footskip=15mm
    }
    
    % Interlineado
    \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.4}% Deprecated. You should use \linespread{1.4} instead.


% -- MARGIN AND LAYOUT --

% -- COLOR SQUARE --
    \usepackage{eso-pic}% I would recommend to use generic shipout hooks instead.
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \definecolor{defaultColor}{HTML}{d9d9d9}
    \definecolor{marginColor1}{HTML}{FBE8E8}

    \newcommand\AtPageUpperRight[1]{\AtPageUpperLeft{\makebox[\paperwidth][r]{#1}}}% Would be a valid definition of the command, which is not provided by eso-pic.

% Custom margin square command
    \newcommand{\marginsquare}[1]{%
        \AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
            \AtPageUpperRight{% Not really needed
                \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
                    \fill[#1] ($(current page.north east)+(0,-3cm)$) rectangle ($(current page.north east)+(-1.5cm,-4.5cm)$);
                \end{tikzpicture}
            }% see the previous not needed comment
        }%
    }%

    % Apply the margin square to every page
    % NOTE: The definition is broken and therefore commented.
%    \newcommand{\applymarginsquare}{\AddEverypageHook{\marginsquare{marginColor1}}}


    % Initially apply the first color
    %\applymarginsquare
    
% -- COLOR SQUARE --

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lastpage} % To reference last page's number

% -- FANCY HEADER, FOOTER AND CHAPTERS --
    \usepackage{fancyhdr} % Headers and footers
    \usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}
    % Color of the chapter
    \newcommand{\colortitlechap}{\color[rgb]{0.6,0.6,0.6}} % color of the chapter title <<<
    \newcommand{\colornumberchap}{\color[rgb]{0.6,0.6,0.6}} % color of the chapter number <<<<
    \newcommand{\colorbackchap}{\colorbox{defaultColor}} % color of the background rules <<<

    \makeatletter

    \renewcommand{\DOCH}{%
    \settowidth{\py}{\CNoV\thechapter}
    \addtolength{\py}{-10pt}% 
    \fboxsep=0pt%
    \colorbackchap{\rule{0pt}{40pt}\parbox[b]{\textwidth}{\hfill}}%
    \kern-\py\raise20pt%
    \hbox{\colornumberchap\CNoV\thechapter}\\%
    }

    \renewcommand{\DOTI}[1]{%
    \nointerlineskip\raggedright%
    \fboxsep=\myhi%
    \vskip-1ex%
    \colorbackchap{\parbox[t]{\mylen}{\CTV\FmTi{\colortitlechap#1}}}\par\nobreak%
    \vskip 40\p@%
    }

    \renewcommand{\DOTIS}[1]{%
    \fboxsep=0pt%
    \colorbackchap{\rule{0pt}{40pt}\parbox[b]{\textwidth}{\hfill}}\\%
    \nointerlineskip\raggedright%
    \fboxsep=\myhi%
    \colorbackchap{\parbox[t]{\mylen}{\CTV\FmTi{\colortitlechap#1}}}\par\nobreak%
    }

    \makeatother

    % Header and footer
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \cfoot{}
    \usepackage{lastpage} % To reference last page's number
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.3mm}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0mm} % 0.3mm
    \renewcommand{\footruleskip}{0mm} % 5mm
    
    % Número de página en el pie de página
    \fancyfoot[C]{\textbf{Página \thepage \hspace{1pt} de \pageref{LastPage}}}
    
    \fancypagestyle{plain}{% % <-- this is new
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}

    % Redefine chaptermark to preserve case 
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{Capítulo \thechapter\ : #1}{}}
    \renewcommand{\chaptername}{Capítulo}

% -- FANCY HEADER, FOOTER AND CHAPTERS --


\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand*\contentsname{ÍNDICE DE CONTENIDOS}
\tableofcontents

\renewcommand{\colorbackchap}{\colorbox{marginColor1}} % color of the background rules <<<
\chapter{INTRODUCCIÓN}
% Change the margin square color for the next chapter
% NOTE: Replaced the broken definition by a working usage of \marginsquare
%\renewcommand{\applymarginsquare}{\AddEverypageHook{\marginsquare{marginColor1}}}
\marginsquare{marginColor1}
\section{Some dummy text}
\blindtext[10]

\end{document}

But because of using tikzpicture with remember picture,overlay and current page.north east, you could simply remove \AtPageUpperRight:
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}

% -- MARGIN AND LAYOUT --
    \usepackage{geometry} 
    \geometry{
     includefoot,
     a4paper,
     total={170mm,257mm},
     left=27mm,
     top=40mm,
     headsep=10mm,
     right=27mm,
     bottom=27mm,
     footskip=15mm
    }
    
    % Interlineado
    \linespread{1.4}


% -- MARGIN AND LAYOUT --

% -- COLOR SQUARE --
    \usepackage{eso-pic}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \definecolor{defaultColor}{HTML}{d9d9d9}
    \definecolor{marginColor1}{HTML}{FBE8E8}


% Custom margin square command
    \newcommand{\marginsquare}[1]{%
        \AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
                \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
                    \fill[#1] ($(current page.north east)+(0,-3cm)$) rectangle ($(current page.north east)+(-1.5cm,-4.5cm)$);
                \end{tikzpicture}%
        }%
    }

    % Apply the margin square to every page
    % NOTE: The definition is broken and therefore commented.
%    \newcommand{\applymarginsquare}{\AddEverypageHook{\marginsquare{marginColor1}}}


    % Initially apply the first color
    %\applymarginsquare
    
% -- COLOR SQUARE --

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lastpage} % To reference last page's number

% -- FANCY HEADER, FOOTER AND CHAPTERS --
    \usepackage{fancyhdr} % Headers and footers
    \usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}
    % Color of the chapter
    \newcommand{\colortitlechap}{\color[rgb]{0.6,0.6,0.6}} % color of the chapter title <<<
    \newcommand{\colornumberchap}{\color[rgb]{0.6,0.6,0.6}} % color of the chapter number <<<<
    \newcommand{\colorbackchap}{\colorbox{defaultColor}} % color of the background rules <<<

    \makeatletter

    \renewcommand{\DOCH}{%
    \settowidth{\py}{\CNoV\thechapter}
    \addtolength{\py}{-10pt}% 
    \fboxsep=0pt%
    \colorbackchap{\rule{0pt}{40pt}\parbox[b]{\textwidth}{\hfill}}%
    \kern-\py\raise20pt%
    \hbox{\colornumberchap\CNoV\thechapter}\\%
    }

    \renewcommand{\DOTI}[1]{%
    \nointerlineskip\raggedright%
    \fboxsep=\myhi%
    \vskip-1ex%
    \colorbackchap{\parbox[t]{\mylen}{\CTV\FmTi{\colortitlechap#1}}}\par\nobreak%
    \vskip 40\p@%
    }

    \renewcommand{\DOTIS}[1]{%
    \fboxsep=0pt%
    \colorbackchap{\rule{0pt}{40pt}\parbox[b]{\textwidth}{\hfill}}\\%
    \nointerlineskip\raggedright%
    \fboxsep=\myhi%
    \colorbackchap{\parbox[t]{\mylen}{\CTV\FmTi{\colortitlechap#1}}}\par\nobreak%
    }

    \makeatother

    % Header and footer
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \cfoot{}
    \usepackage{lastpage} % To reference last page's number
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.3mm}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0mm} % 0.3mm
    \renewcommand{\footruleskip}{0mm} % 5mm
    
    % Número de página en el pie de página
    \fancyfoot[C]{\textbf{Página \thepage \hspace{1pt} de \pageref{LastPage}}}
    
    \fancypagestyle{plain}{% % <-- this is new
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}

    % Redefine chaptermark to preserve case 
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{Capítulo \thechapter\ : #1}{}}
    \renewcommand{\chaptername}{Capítulo}

% -- FANCY HEADER, FOOTER AND CHAPTERS --


\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand*\contentsname{ÍNDICE DE CONTENIDOS}
\tableofcontents

\renewcommand{\colorbackchap}{\colorbox{marginColor1}} % color of the background rules <<<
\chapter{INTRODUCCIÓN}
% Change the margin square color for the next chapter
% NOTE: Replaced the broken definition by a working usage of \marginsquare
%\renewcommand{\applymarginsquare}{\AddEverypageHook{\marginsquare{marginColor1}}}
\marginsquare{marginColor1}
\section{Some dummy text}
\blindtext[10]

\end{document}

